# Why the recurrence relation of Markov chain can be written as the following?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am reading E-Li-Vanden-Eijnden's *Applied Stochastic Analysis*, and the author claims:

The recurrence relation of $\boldsymbol{\mu}_n=\boldsymbol{\mu}_{n-1}\boldsymbol{P}$, where $\boldsymbol{\mu}_n$ is the distribution of $X_n$, and $\boldsymbol{P}$ is the transition matrix, can be written as $$\mu_{n,i}=\mu_{n-1,i}\left(1-\sum_{j\in S,j\neq i}p_{ij}\right)+\sum_{j\in S, j\neq i}\mu_{n-1,j}p_{ji}$$
where $S$ is the state space, $p_{ij}=P(X_n=j|X_{n-1}=i)$, and $p_{ji}=P(X_n=i|X_{n-1}=j)$.

I understand the intuition behind this equation: the first term on RHS gives the total probability of not making a transition from state $i$, and the second term gives the probability of transitioning from one state $j\neq i$ to state $i$. However, I do not know how to prove this rigorously.

My current attempt is to follow how I understand the equation, by separating them into two parts using conditional probability, but I am showing little progress. Can anyone give a proof of this equation? I will update the post if I yield further progress. This might be a naive question, but I am new to Markov chains. Thank you.

**Edit:** Thanks to someone in the chat,

$\Bbb P(X_n = i) = \sum_j \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = j) \cdot \Bbb P(X_{n-1} = j) = \Bbb P(X_n = i \mid X_{n-1} = i) \cdot \Bbb P(X_{n-1} = i) + \sum_{j\neq i} \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = j) \cdot \Bbb P(X_{n-1} = j)$

$\sum_j \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = i) = 1$ so $\Bbb P(X_n = i \mid X_{n-1} = i) = 1 - \sum_{j \neq i} \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = i)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to someone in the chat,

$\Bbb P(X_n = i) = \sum_j \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = j) \cdot \Bbb P(X_{n-1} = j) = \Bbb P(X_n = i \mid X_{n-1} = i) \cdot \Bbb P(X_{n-1} = i) + \sum_{j\neq i} \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = j) \cdot \Bbb P(X_{n-1} = j)$

$\sum_j \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = i) = 1$ so $\Bbb P(X_n = i \mid X_{n-1} = i) = 1 - \sum_{j \neq i} \Bbb P(X_n = j \mid X_{n-1} = i)$